# Risks of AJAX calls to asmx

Tags: asp.net, ajax, web-services, post, sitefinity

Currently working on an ajax call to an ASP web service (.asmx).

In a situation where I POST to the url/.asmx/WebMethod, am I exposing information of any kind?

In the 'WebMethod' I am running a PostJsonAsync that calls an API and passes along a json string.

As I am still learning, I've been told that calling any public [WebMethod] exposes the code, but I am not sure how that is possible.

Is it possible at all for a user to access the WebMethod server-side code that I have and peek into the API calls that are available?

I've attempted some minor security methods.. We are working with Sitefinity CMS. What I did was call a WebMethod that receives the CurrentUserIdentity and returns a GUID. If the current user is logged in, it returns a valid Guid, if not it returns a Guid full of zeros.

Then, I call the WebMethod containing my API call and post a json object along with the valid or invalid GUID. The server-side WebMethod code will then verify if the GUID is valid and continues based on if a UserProfile can be generated.

To me, this seems to be secure, but I've been told that this still leaves the WebMethod exposed as well as the API. I am however just not understanding what is exposed and what can be used.

If anybody can direct me to any resources that has more information on this, or if anybody can advise me on WebService security, I would appreciate it.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

If you're calling the methods via AJAX, then they are exposed to the public...and can be called by anything that can make a call to your server. That being said, there's nothing wrong with it unless you're doing something that's easily abused.

In your particular case, it sounds like the code is accepting a GUID that is assumed to have come from the first API call. If that's really the case, you may want to rethink how the mechanism works. Adding authentication checks for each method that needs to be restricted may be a better solution.

Comment: yeah i've been trying to work out some solutions involving legitimate authentication checks. thank you for the response